# OCP - Jenking persistent - old version?

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I have an OCP 4.4.11 running on IBM cloud.
I decided to install jenkins-persistent that's provided by RedHat. But the version installed is 2.222.1, which is quite old I would say. Is it possible to update to some latest one?

The jenkins image itself seems to be coming from openshift's imagestream:

```
kind: ImageStream
apiVersion: image.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/display-name: Jenkins
    openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck: '2020-07-27T14:15:11Z'
    samples.operator.openshift.io/version: 4.4.11
  selfLink: /apis/image.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/openshift/imagestreams/jenkins
  resourceVersion: '9085485'
  name: jenkins
  uid: ac909c0b-072e-43bc-a1b6-4e7b31aea5b5
  creationTimestamp: '2020-06-30T09:35:08Z'
  generation: 79
  namespace: openshift
  labels:
    samples.operator.openshift.io/managed: 'true'
spec:
  lookupPolicy:
    local: false
  tags:
    - name: '2'
      annotations:
        description: >-
          Provides a Jenkins 2.X server on RHEL 7. For more information about
          using this container image, including OpenShift considerations, see
          https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/blob/master/README.md.
        iconClass: icon-jenkins
        openshift.io/display-name: Jenkins 2.X
        openshift.io/provider-display-name: 'Red Hat, Inc.'
        tags: jenkins
        version: 2.x
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: >-
          quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:30afdb96156bc98c67f07dbdfb1878cffca84daf9fd0869187cd2c7ad627a995
      generation: 77
      importPolicy: {}
      referencePolicy:
        type: Local
```

Link from the YAML: https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/blob/master/README.md

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins image available with OCP are based on Jenkins LTS released

(Almost) each time you'll upgrade OCP, the image and version of Jenkins will also be upgraded, so it is not advised to play with the deployment. The OCP Jenkins  image embeds many useful plugins. You can safely upgrade the plugins from the Jenkins UI if they are compatible with the version of Jenkins (The UI will tell you if not)

In any case, nothing force you to use the Jenkins images provided with OCP, you can deploy your own flavor of Jenkins and add the plugins required to interact with OCP itself (Kubernetes plugin, OCP plugin, configure OIDC for jenkins to OCP etc)