# Openshift jenkins how to specify jenkins version?

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I'm using Redhat images for Jenkins:
https://quay.io/repository/openshift/origin-jenkins?tab=tags

As noted here, they have a file with the Jenkins version specified:
https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/blob/57d4ffbf08c29bd2e74fb4a5bec5240b62c1f313/2/contrib/openshift/jenkins-version.txt#L1

The image tags are tight to the openshift version, rather than the Jenkins version.

**The question is:**
Is there a way to configure/override a Jenkins version?

I have looked at the available docs and could not find any info regarding that.

I'm aware of the answer [OCP - Jenking persistent - old version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63119605/ocp-jenking-persistent-old-version), but I want to avoid a lot of manual configuration which is needed to set up a custom Jenkins image which will work inside openshift.